Minimizing total variation under constraint
For $p\in[0,1]$, we write $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$
to denote the Bernoulli measure on $\{0,1\}$;
that is, $\mathrm{Ber}(p)(0)=1-p$,
$\mathrm{Ber}(p)(1)=p$.
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\in[0,1]^n$,
$\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ denotes
the product of $n$ Bernoulli distributions with parameters $p_i$:
$$
\mathrm{Ber}(p) =
\mathrm{Ber}(p_1) \otimes \mathrm{Ber}(p_2)\otimes \ldots \otimes \mathrm{Ber}(p_n).
$$
Thus, $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$ is a probability measure on
$\{0,1\}^n$,
with
$$
\mathrm{Ber}(p)(x) 
= \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{x_i}(1-p_i)^{1-x_i}
,
\qquad
x\in\{0,1\}^n,
$$
Consider the following (non-convex*) optimization problem:
Minimize
$$
\lVert\mathrm{Ber}(p)
-
\mathrm{Ber}(q)\rVert_1
$$
over all $p,q\in[0,1]^n$
under the constraints $p_i-q_i=\varepsilon_i\ge0$
and $\sum_{i=1}^n \varepsilon_i=\ell$.
I am only interested in the case of even $n$.
I thought I could prove, but now only conjecture
(with very compelling numerical evidence)
that the unique minimum
occurs at $p_i=1/2+\ell/(2n)$
and $q_i=1/2-\ell/(2n)$.
How does one prove this?
Warning: the above is only optimal for even $n$, not odd.
*I had previously wrongly claimed that the problem was convex.
Update Aug-22-2024.
The above conjecture easily follows from this stronger one, for which there is very strong numerical evidence:
Poisson binomial conjecture

Once we prove that the objective is convex, the rest follows easily from symmetry. The optimal solution must be invariant under the permutation group (acting on the indices of $p_i$ and $q_i$) and "reflections": $(p, q) \mapsto (1 - q, 1- p)$. The only fixed point is your solution.

Note that this is false for odd n, so where does your argument fail there?

Are you sure that the objective is convex?

Actually now less sure.

My plot shows that it is not a convex function of $x$ even when all $p_i = x + 0.1$ and $q_i = x$, $n = 3$.

you're right -- it's not convex!
but the claim about the minimum still appears to be true

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm tempted to try proving this by induction on $n$, but the fact that it only applies to even $n$ seems like a big barrier. Is there a form of the conjecture that holds for all $n$? Can you at least prove it for $n=2$?

Induction -- as well as all other "local" methods seem to fail badly here. I can prove the minimizer claim for $n=2$, but not that it's unique. The minimizer for odd $n$ has all $p_i$s equal and all $q_i$s too but otherwise doesn't have the nice, simple form that even $n$ does.
